# List of environment variable in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, environment-variables

I need list of environment variable that are used in Objective C.

e.g `NSObjCMessageEnabled: YES` which is used for method logging. Please list down all such methods.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2124/_index.html), the list varies from release-to-release. E.g., for my OSX 10.2.8, the following debugging environment variables exist (beside of **NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled**):

- **OBJC_PRINT_OPTIONS**: list which options are set
- **OBJC_PRINT_IMAGES**: log image and library names as they are loaded
- **OBJC_PRINT_LOAD_METHODS**: log calls to class and category +load methods
- **OBJC_PRINT_INITIALIZE_METHODS**: log calls to class +initialize methods
- **OBJC_PRINT_RESOLVED_METHODS**: log methods created by +resolveClassMethod: and +resolveInstanceMethod:
- **OBJC_PRINT_CLASS_SETUP**: log progress of class and category setup
- **OBJC_PRINT_PROTOCOL_SETUP**: log progress of protocol setup
- **OBJC_PRINT_IVAR_SETUP**: log processing of non-fragile ivars
- **OBJC_PRINT_VTABLE_SETUP**: log processing of class vtables
- **OBJC_PRINT_VTABLE_IMAGES**: print vtable images showing overridden methods
- **OBJC_PRINT_CACHE_SETUP**: log processing of method caches
- **OBJC_PRINT_FUTURE_CLASSES**: log use of future classes for toll-free bridging
- **OBJC_PRINT_GC**: log some GC operations
- **OBJC_PRINT_PREOPTIMIZATION**: log preoptimization courtesy of dyld shared cache
- **OBJC_PRINT_CXX_CTORS**: log calls to C++ ctors and dtors for instance variables
- **OBJC_PRINT_EXCEPTIONS**: log exception handling
- **OBJC_PRINT_EXCEPTION_THROW**: log backtrace of every objc_exception_throw()
- **OBJC_PRINT_ALT_HANDLERS**: log processing of exception alt handlers
- **OBJC_PRINT_REPLACED_METHODS**: log methods replaced by category implementations
- **OBJC_PRINT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS**: warn about calls to deprecated runtime functions
- **OBJC_PRINT_POOL_HIGHWATER**: log high-water marks for autorelease pools
- **OBJC_PRINT_CUSTOM_RR:** log classes with un-optimized custom retain/release methods
- **OBJC_PRINT_CUSTOM_AWZ**: log classes with un-optimized custom allocWithZone methods
- **OBJC_DEBUG_UNLOAD**: warn about poorly-behaving bundles when unloaded
- **OBJC_DEBUG_FRAGILE_SUPERCLASSES**: warn about subclasses that may have been broken by subsequent changes to superclasses
- **OBJC_DEBUG_FINALIZERS**: warn about classes that implement -dealloc but not -finalize
- **OBJC_DEBUG_NIL_SYNC**: warn about @synchronized(nil), which does no synchronization
- **OBJC_DEBUG_NONFRAGILE_IVARS**: capriciously rearrange non-fragile ivars
- **OBJC_DEBUG_ALT_HANDLERS**: record more info about bad alt handler use
- **OBJC_USE_INTERNAL_ZONE**: allocate runtime data in a dedicated malloc zone
- **OBJC_DISABLE_GC**: force GC OFF, even if the executable wants it on
- **OBJC_DISABLE_VTABLES**: disable vtable dispatch
- **OBJC_DISABLE_PREOPTIMIZATION**: disable preoptimization courtesy of dyld shared cache

If you want to get the list at your system, set `OBJC_HELP` to `YES` and start a program. Then, the list is dumped.

Comment: Any way of getting method entry line number using environment variables?

Comment: @user1882057: Not in this version, but for your own code you can log and use the `__LINE__`.